# Breaking a line with RSCRLF and not just CRLF using Java (1.8)

Tags: java, newline, filestream

I am currently working on a file reader (File Input Stream and Buffered Reader) to read lines from a file (This is a proprietary log file from an application and it has CRLF as line feed but RSCRLF as Record Separator. But when I use Java File Readers, the lines are read based on default CR/LF and considered as different lines even though they are of same line till the Record Separator (RS). I  started reading the characters one by one (instead of lines) and got a byte[] array of characters. But how do I check for RSCRLF characters and break it at that point?
from ASCII table:

```
RS -> CHAR, 30 -> DEC, 1E -> HEX
CR -> CHAR, 13 -> DEC, D -> HEX
LF -> CHAR, 10 -> DEC, A -> HEX
```

Any ideas? Not looking for a code but an idea on how to read through bytes and find RSCRLF together to break at that point?

Thanks

Comment: You could potentially use a `Scanner` with a custom delimiter.

Comment: Thank you Jake. I think this would work if I can convert RS -> CHAR, 30 -> DEC, 1E -> HEX to a string literal (like CR (\r) and LF (\n) ) as useDelimiter for scanner takes only String pattern. is there any way I can provide RS as a string literal? I have seen  all the examples on google using \r or ]n as string literals but not for RS ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use a `Scanner` with a custom delimiter, here's what that would look like:

```
...
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(readable);
scanner.useDelimiter("\u001E\r\n");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String record = scanner.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Jake. I was testing with "\\x1e" and looks like it worked properly. But I'll try with this delimiter and see if it works as expected.